# Google Sheets random name generator

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering if anyone had a script or way to randomly select a name based on a list.   So heres the problem, i have one person who entered the raffle one time.  The next person entered lets say 5 times and so on.  The fist person should only get one chance to win while the next person should get 5 chances to win

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the top row for labels and names in ColumnA, 'times' in ColumnB then:

In C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=sum(B$2:B2)
```

In D1:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,Sum(B:B))
```

Then:

```
=iferror(index(A:A,match(D1,C:C,0)),index(A:A,1+match(D1,C:C,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, list the "next person" five times as often as the other two, select the complete list, apply Data > Randomise range and pick the one at the top of the list, say.